# Detect MouseUp in a Delphi Button Component when An Error Occurs

Tags: delphi, button, state, mouseup

I made a button component in Delphi, and I write a code with error (strtoint('a');) in my button mouseup event. When I click the button, an error message raising and the button state remains pressed. There is the same problem with TSpeedButton too, but TButton has not this problem (I think because it is a standard windows control). Is there any code to add to my button component to remove this bug?

Comment: You could of course handle the exception in your event handler. In the case of bad input, the best handling is probably to do nothing at all. Or use TryStrToInt, as suggested.

Comment: You should always catch exceptions inside event handlers. Don't call it a problem with the control, it's a problem with your code.

Comment: Try it yourself. Drop a TButton and a TSpeedButton on your form write a code with error in the mouseup event, and see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I should add code to restore button to normal state, in WM_KILLFOCUS message procedure.